# Login to chromebook using a local password?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, chromebook

I use a unique 64 character password for my google account, together with 2FA.

I have a Chromebook as a secondary computer, but find it really difficult to use as you have to use your google password to login.

Im aware you can set a pin to login instead of a password, but this doesn't work really well, as you can only use the pin to access the account from sleep, not from switching users, or from a full Reeboot.

Is it possible to set a seperate password just to login to my user on the chromebook, so that i could use a unique 12 character password for chromebook local login, but still use the 64 character password for the google account login, so that its more secure against people trying to access it over the web.

Comment: I have set up [Smart Lock](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6070209?hl=en) but have experienced issues. Sometimes it does not work after release upgrades or when I haven't used it for weeks. I second your request for a solution to use an alternative password or mechanism.

Comment: Yu could just add a second account with an simpler password. Or you change the password to a simpler password and and change to a two factor authentication for the Google account. Would one of those options be a viable solution for you?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with my kids. I don't want them to have their Google account passwords as that would enable them to do things like turn off SafeSearch or make other changes either deliberately or by accident but I do want them to be able to log into a Chromebook for school work etc.

What I did was use the "Sign in another user" option which, if done correctly will mean both accounts can be accessed via PIN from sleep mode. It does mean each user can access the other user's account so you need to trust each other but it does mean you can keep settings etc separate.

Make sure all accounts have a PIN set up.
Log into one account.
Go to the clock area bottom right and click.
Then click the user icon in the top right of the box that popped up.
Use the "Sign in another user" option and sign in the user you want to add.
Put put the ChromeBook into sleep and then wake it.
Sign in the new user with their password.

Now when waking you should be able to choose which user and just use the PIN.

Not perfect but it may help someone.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add if you reboot you will have to set this up again but it isn't a massive task.